# jQuery Traversal -- Find an Element Relative to Common Ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I frequently find I'm needing to select an element that is nearby, typically within a common container, but which is not a sibling or within the same "tree line". For example, given this HTML:

```
<div id="container-left" class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <button class="more-link">Show Extras</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="tidbits">
            <p>Lorem ipsum beep bop boop</p>
            <p class="extra hidden">Exxtra info about lorem ipsum!</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container-right" class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <button class="more-link">Show Extras</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="tidbits">
            <p>Lorem ipsum beep bop boop</p>
            <p class="extra hidden">Exxtra info about lorem ipsum!</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'll do is attach an event listener to the "Show Extras" `button`s, which target the `p` tags with class of `extra`, and on click, toggle the `hidden` class. So (using jQuery) I typically select like this:

```
$(".more-link").on("click",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $extraElement = $this.closest(".container").find(".extra");
    $extraElement.toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

My question: is there a better way to select the `extra` element than the `.closest().find()` combo? Something about it just feels a little clunky.

Comment: *"My question: is there a better way to select the extra element than the `.closest().find()` combo? Something about it just feels a little clunky."* No, not really. That's pretty much how you do it (and I wouldn't say it's particularly clunky :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

well.. you could navigate to sidebar siblings and find extra... but the mess would be similar...

Other way to do it is to generate a HTML5 data attribute at button:

```
<button class="more-link" data-extra='#some-generated-extra-id'>Show Extras</button>
...
<p id='some-generated-extra-id' class="extra hidden">Exxtra info about lorem ipsum!</p>
```

your code:

```
$(".more-link").on("click",function() {
    var $extraElement = $($(this).data('extra'));
    $extraElement.toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Interesting, but when you refer to a "generated" id, is that me writing a specific id for every button/target pair, or is that being programatically generated somehow?

Comment: I mean "programatically generated somehow", assuming you have some PHP/ASP/Java whatever server there generating that HTML list. You do?

Comment: Gotcha. It seems like the effort to generate unique ids is more than the time being saved by the trimmer jQuery selector, though.